# ror data-filter category gem pagination not working in the second page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, data-filtering

This code is working fine in first page but when I move on to the second and the other pages it shows them all without filtering

I am using `gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.4"`

in the controller

```
def index
    @galleries=Gallery.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 19)
end

private
  def gallery_attributes
    gallery_attributes = params.require(:gallery).permit([:product_name,:image1,:image2,:image3,:image4,:image5,:title1,:title2,:title3,:title4,:title5,:video,:videotitle])
  end
```

in the index

```
<span class="list active" data-filter="all-items">All</span>
      <% @galleries.select(:product_name).map(&:product_name).uniq.reject { |c| c.empty? }.each do |g| %>
      <span class="list" data-filter="<%= g  %>"><%= g  %></span>
      <% end %>

  <% count = 1 %>
      <% @galleries.each do |g| %>
        <% if g.image1.present? %>
          <div class="item <%= g.product_name %>">
            <%= g.product_name %>
            <%= image_tag g.image1.url,alt: "conversion", style: "width:100%", onclick: "openModal();currentSlide(#{count})" ,class: "hover-shadow cursor",alt: g.title1, title: g.title1%>
            <p class="desc" onclick= "openModal();currentSlide(<%= count %>)" ><%=  g.title1 %></p>
          </div>
          <% count = count + 1 %>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: I think it should be `Gallery.paginate(...)` not `Gallery.all.paginate(...)`. Also, where is the `gallery_attributes` method called?

Comment: Gallery attributes is in the gallery controller

Comment: yes I can see that he `gallery_attributes` method is defined in the gallery controller, but where is it used? I can also see your index method in the controller, but no mention of any filter parameters. How are the filter parameters passed in?